# ORA-06550: Encountered "end-of-file" when expecting the following: . ( % ; The query runs fine, but is giving errors in the block

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure personWithGivenCity(city1 in varchar) as
cursor c1 is select p.name 
              from person p 
              join address ad 
              on p.name=ad.name 
              where ad.city=city1;
c c1%rowtype;
begin
    open c1;
    loop
        fetch c1 into c;
        exit when c1%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(c.name);
    end loop;
    close c1;
end;
/

-- Block which class the procedure
declare
    city varchar2(10):='Vasco';
begin
    personWithGivenCity(city);
end;
/
```

The query works fine without the block. But I'm getting `end-of-file` error at `line 3 column 11`.

Table structures

Person

```
name varchar2(10) primary key, 
gender varchar2(10), 
age number
```

Address

```
name varchar2(10) references person(name), 
hno number, 
laneno number, 
city varchar2(10), 
state varchar2(10)
```

The error

```
ORA-06550: line 3, column 11: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: . ( % ; for
```

Comment: The code is working fine localy here.

Comment: I'm trying it on SQL fiddle and I'm getting the above error. When I did it with Oracle SQL Worksheet, every row was printing twice. I don't the problem.